# Jquery File Browser

Tags: jquery, html

I want to implement a Jquery File browser using HTML and Jquery only.
I have been browsing through various jquery plugins, not able to find one , that can work with only HTML/Jquery (no serverside connectors).
I have gone through http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/ .

Any help / suggestions will be helpfull

Comment: This is not possible without server-side connectors. How do you expect jQuery to be able to access a server without a connector?

Comment: the html file will be opened in the local browser only , where it exists in file system, and a local folder 's files will be displayed in the page

Comment: @Andy : Please suggest !!

Comment: @Andy how would that work in a local context? He doesn't want to do *anything* on a server

Comment: I think , you got me wrong ... I want something like http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/ , where the htmlfile and the folder i want to browse both are present in the lcoal m/c itself.

Comment: AFAIK the browser cannot query the file system like that for security reasons

Comment: It is already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767408/open-file-browser-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Browsers will not allow you to get the correct path of the file in your local m/c specially in IE and Safari.

Comment: any solution for only Mozilla ?

Comment: None. I think even Mozilla wont allow it.

Answer (score -1):

only HTML/JS is not enough, you need some server-side, try elFinder,
[www.elfinder.org](http://elfinder.org/)